# Does phoneGap support normal web?

Tags: cordova

Does phoneGap supports normal web page, if so can i have the link which i can go through?

thanks

sri

Answer (score 3):

Definitely, it can load in your existing UIWebView instance, or into a ChildBrowser [plugin](http://github.com/purplecabbage/PhoneGap-Plugins).

Comment: Phonegap 1.2.0 is sometimes opening Safari for me, was there functionality for this added between the release 1.2.0 and August of 2010? (When this answer was published.)  If so, how is that functionality controlled (I don't want my links to open Safari, but they are.)

Comment: Looks like if <a> tags use define the target property then they open in Safari, or if Javascript calls window.open it opens in Safari.

Comment: Uhh, window.location.href = "http://blah.com"; opens in Safari, and so does <iframe src="http://blah.com"></iframe>, but <a href="http://blah.com"> doesn't. How utterly confusing.

Comment: https://github.com/callback/callback-ios/blob/master/PhoneGapLib/Classes/PhoneGapDelegate.m#L669 reveals that there's a OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView policy that is part of the determination.  Failing that, it comes down to `navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther && mainDocument != nil`. ~NavTypeOther signifies not a link click, back/fwd button, reload, form re/submit. So basically, only link clicks open in the UIWebView.

Comment: @nmr that's because PhoneGap will change all A links and an onclick event instead; it cannot do that auto-magically for window.location not iframes...

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me yet, can you elaborate on it? How will it change A tags, and why?

Answer (score 2):

You can link from a PhoneGap app to an external web page - it will just open it in Mobile Safari (for the iPhone) or the Android Browser.