# What controls whether PhoneGap opens an external browser / Safari?

Tags: cordova

Sometimes PhoneGap opens web pages in Safari, sometimes it opens them in its UIWebView, what controls this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Does phoneGap support normal web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210543/does-phonegap-support-normal-web/3505350#comment10019245_3505350):

https://github.com/callback/callback-ios/blob/master/PhoneGapLib/Classes/PhoneGapDelegate.m#L669 reveals that:

1. if the URL has scheme gap:// it does not open Safari
2. if the URL has scheme file:// it does not open Safari
3. if the OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView policy is set it does not open Safari.
4. if `navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther && mainDocument != nil` then it does open Safari.

Elaborating on 4:

- ~NavTypeOther signifies that the navigation is not from: a link click, back/fwd button, reload, or form re/submission. (AKA `window.location.href assignment`, or `window.open(...)`)
- `mainDocument != nil` signifies that the link is not from an iFrame? and/or doesn't have a target?

So basically, I think that only link clicks open in the UIWebView (unless they're gap:// or file:// links, or that policy is set.)